# Convolution of $L^{1}$ functions is well-defined

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, convolution

> Let $f,g\in L^{1}(\mathbb R^d).$ The convolution of $f$ and $g$ is the function $f\ast g$ defined by $$(f\ast g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x-y)g(y)\,dy.$$
>   Show that $(f\ast g)(x)$ is well-defined for a.e. $x\in\mathbb R^d$. That is, show that for a.e. $x\in\mathbb R^d$, the function $y\mapsto f(x-y)g(y)$ is integrable (in particular, show that it is measurable).

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$
The function $f^{\star}(x,y)=\vert f(x-y)\vert$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^{d}\times\mathbb R^{d}.$ Also, the function $g^{\star}(x,y)=\vert g(x)\vert$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d.$ It follows that $h:\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ defined by $h(x,y)=\vert f(x-y)g(y)\vert$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d,$ since it is a product of measurable functions. Since $h$ is also non-negative, Tonelli's theorem and translation invariance of the Lebesgue integral  imply that
\begin{equation}\begin{split}\int_{\mathbb R^d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}\vert h(x,y)\vert\,dy\,dx &=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\left(\int_{\mathbb R^d}\vert f(x-y)\vert\vert g(y)\vert\,dx\right)\,dy\\&=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\left(\int_{\mathbb R^d}\vert f(x)\vert\,dx\right)\vert g(y)\vert\,dy\\&=\left(\int_{\mathbb R^d}\vert f(x)\vert\,dx\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb R^d}\vert g(y)\vert\,dy\right)\\&=\|f\|_{1}\|g\|_{1}\\&<\infty.\end{split}\end{equation}
$\color{red}{\text{This implies that } \int_{\mathbb R^d}\vert f(x-y)\vert\vert g(y)\vert\,dy<\infty \text{ for a.e } x\in\mathbb R^d}.$ It follows that the function $y\mapsto f(x-y)g(y)$ is integrable for a.e. $x\in\mathbb R^d$, and hence measurable.

---

Is my argument correct?

My main concern is with the claim in red.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: One of your integrals is disappearing on that red line. You might add a tad more justification for why we can do this. Otherwise, good proof.

Comment: You can look at $h_n(x) = \int_{[-n,n]^d} \min(|f(y)|,n)\min(|g(x-y)|,n)dy$ which is well-defined then it suffices to say $ \|h_n\|_1 \le\|f\|_1\|g\|_1<\infty$ which means $ \mu(\{ x, h_n(x) > m\} \le \frac{\|f\|_1\|g\|_1}{m}$ and hence $\|f g(x-.)\|_1=\lim_{n \to \infty} h_n(x)<\infty$ for almost every $x$

Comment: Your argument is fine. If a nonnegative extended real valued function $\phi$ is integrable then $\phi <\infty$ almost everywhere. In fact what you have written is the standard proof found in most texts in Real Analysis.